# WubiUEFI on Legacy BIOS

Tags: uefi, grub-efi

Does WubiUEFI, a fork of Wubi, work on legacy BIOS? They say that you can use it on EFI with legacy BIOS mode, however, I am really worried if I render my system unusable. Also, my system is legacy BIOS only. It doesn't come with UEFI.

Comment: I'm not sure, but going off of [their wiki introduction](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#introduction), it looks like it does: "In the past the issues of official versions only affected newer UEFI systems **but meanwhile the issues affect older systems with legacy BIOS, too**. … So, it was time to create Wubiuefi."

Comment: @chai-t-rex you say that we can only find out with trial and error?

Comment: You can also [ask them on their issues page](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/issues/new) to add to their wiki whether old non-UEFI BIOS machines work .

Comment: If you value your system and data you will do a full system and data backup before you install another OS, Ubuntu, or otherwise, wubi, or otherwise. In my personal opinion I would not use wubi as, IMO, it is more likely to fail than a standard install as it adds one layer of complexity (a linux file system within windows) and a number of potential points of failure (probably can not boot Ubuntu via wubi if your windows install is corrupt for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does WubiUEFI, a fork of Wubi, work on legacy BIOS?

Yes, it does. If Windows is not installed in UEFI mode, Wubiuefi uses the 
boot method of the [original Wubi](https://launchpad.net/wubi). see ["Does Wubiuefi work also without UEFI ?"](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki/FAQ#does-wubiuefi-work-also-without-uefi-)

i.e. It depends on the installation mode of Windows. If your system is Legacy BIOS only, Windows is definitively installed in Legacy BIOS mode (non UEFI mode).